# Unfocus text input when dismissing keyboard in react-native (Android)

Tags: javascript, react-native

When clicking outside the TextInput the keyboard is dismissed and the input field unfocused. But this does not happen when clicking on 'Done' on the keyboard, this action does only dismiss the keyboard but does not unfocus the input field.

Is there anyway to unfocus the TextInput when clicking done on the keyboard (on android)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is to use setNativeProps

```
<TextInput ref={ component => this.myInput = component } 
  onSubmitEditing={(e) => this.myInput.setNativeProps({enable: false}))
/>
```

Of course you'll need to re-activate it when needed.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1855/files